# Generate linear fit samples using the standard errors from scipy.stats.linregress

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I'm using [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) to fit a group of points as seen in the plot below. The points are the blue circles, the linear fit is the black line and the grey lines are samples taken using the `stderr` and `intercept_stderr` values to sample the `slope` and `intercept` values using [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) (code below).

[image]

My question is: given that `stderr` and `intercept_stderr` are *standard errors* and `numpy.random.normal` expects *standard deviations*, should I multiply `stderr` and `intercept_stderr` by $\sqrt{N}$ when sampling?

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

x = np.array([-4.12078708, -3.89764352, -3.77248038, -3.66125475, -3.56117129,
       -3.47019951, -3.3868179 , -3.30985686, -3.2383979 , -3.17170652,
       -3.10918616, -3.05034566, -2.99477581, -2.94213208, -2.89212166,
       -2.84449361, -2.79903124, -2.75554612, -2.71387343, -2.67386809,
       -2.63540181, -2.59836054, -2.56264246, -2.52815628, -2.49481986,
       -2.462559  , -2.43130646, -2.40100111, -2.37158722, -2.34301385,
       -2.31523428, -2.28820561, -2.2618883 , -2.23624587, -2.21124457,
       -2.18685312, -2.16304247, -2.13978561, -2.11705736, -2.09483422,
       -2.07309423, -2.05181683, -2.03098275, -2.01057388])
y = np.array([10.54683181, 10.37020828, 10.93819231, 10.1338195 , 10.68036321,
       10.48930797, 10.2340761 , 10.52002056, 10.20343913, 10.29089844,
       10.36190947, 10.26050936, 10.36528216, 10.41799894, 10.40077834,
       10.2513676 , 10.30768792, 10.49377725,  9.73298189, 10.1158334 ,
       10.29359023, 10.38660209, 10.30087358, 10.49464606, 10.23305099,
       10.34389097, 10.29016557, 10.0865885 , 10.338077  , 10.34950896,
       10.15110388, 10.33316701, 10.22837808, 10.3848174 , 10.56872297,
       10.24457621, 10.48255182, 10.39029786, 10.0208671 , 10.17400544,
        9.82086658, 10.51361151, 10.4376062 , 10.18610696])

res = stats.linregress(x, y)

s_vals = np.random.normal(res.slope, res.stderr, 100)
i_vals = np.random.normal(res.intercept, res.intercept_stderr, 100)
for i in range(100):
    plt.plot(x, i_vals[i] + s_vals[i]*x, c='grey', alpha=.1)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, res.intercept + res.slope*x, c='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the end goal of this exercise? The slope and intercept estimates you are using are just estimates calculated using this specific data sample.  Generating random samples should be done using population parameters, which are of course unknown.

Comment: The goal is to show the uncertainty associated with the slope fit. You are probably correct and bootstrapping the data might be a more proper approach

Comment: One could simply generate a NumPy array `x`, define `slope=5`, `inter=7`, and `sigma=2` and compute the endogenous variable via `y=slope*x+inter + np.random.normal(0,sigma,size=len(x))`. I compiled an answer taking that appeals to the uncertainty aspect through visuals, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Indeed, it is an estimate of the standard deviation since *standard error* means *standard deviation of the error of a particular parameter*. No, there is no need to "de-normalize" by multiplying with `np.sqrt(n)`. Finally, however, you might want to change the distribution from which you sample the simulated parameters with that of a [`t-distribution`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.standard_t.html).

#### Qualitative explanation

No further multiplication (e.g. with `np.sqrt(n)`) is needed, i.e. the normalization stays in place. Why is that? Intuitively speaking, slope and intercept parameters are, in a sense, summary statistics of a dataset consisting of pairs *x* and *y*. They characterize the dataset as a whole rather than a single pair of points like *(x_i, y_i)*. Similar to sampling a summary statistic (e.g. the mean over x), we use a normalized estimator for standard deviation. In case of a regression, the average variability of all datapoints in a dataset impacts the estimated variability of the resulting intercept. The square root of the sample size merely balances the sum of the variability across the datapoints relative to their absolute number.

A more rigorous explanation would concern the variance-covariance matrix of the estimator (*β^*). In it, the square root of the elements along the diagonal are the standard errors of the elements of the estimator. In particular, the square root of the first element on the diagonal which represents the standard error of the intercept parameter. With a bit of linear algebra, one can establish a connection between each parameter's standard error (in your case, those of intercept and slope) with that of the regression model. Since the standard error of the regression model *s* is an asymptotically unbiased estimate of the standard deviation of the noise in the data *σ*, a quantitative rationale can be established requiring no re-scaling of the intercept's standard error.

Regarding the distributions from which you sample/simulate the intercept and slope. Rather than a Normal distribution, the standard errors follow the (Student's) t-distribution. See [slide 18](https://people.stat.sc.edu/hansont/stat704/lecture4.pdf). In turn,

```
s_vals = np.random.standard_t(df=len(x)-2, size=100) * res.stderr + res.slope
i_vals = np.random.standard_t(df=len(x)-2, size=100) * res.intercept_stderr + res.intercept
```

However, with sample sizes beyond *n=30*, the realizations will be almost statistically indistinguishable as compares to those sampled from a Gaussian distribution. This is because the t-distribution converges to that of a standard normal distribution rather quickly.

#### Visual explanation

We can skip the quantitative arguments though. What do we expect from estimators based on datasets? The more data we have the more certainty we have about the fixed but unknown location. In turn, if we increase the size *n* of the data, the simulated grey lines should move closer together. This happens when we use the standard error as the `scale` parameter. Increasing the sample size by a factor of 14 brings the grey lines closer. Instead, using the standard error multiplied by `np.sqrt(n)` leaves the grey lines equally far apart even when the dataset size is drastically increased. In fact, we exactly undid the advantage of a higher sample size by multiplying with the square roots of *n*.
[image]